# Does the Plagued curse cancel out the drawback of the Covetous curse?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, curses, oracle

A player of mine is building a [Dual-Cursed Oracle](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/archetypes/paizo-oracle-archetypes/dual-cursed-oracle/). They want to take the [Covetous](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/Oracle/oracle-curses/#Covetous) and the [Plagued](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/Oracle/oracle-curses/#Plagued) curses. That brings up a question.

The [Covetous](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/Oracle/oracle-curses/#Covetous) curse states (emphasis mine)

> You must wear fine non-magical clothing and jewelry worth at least 50
> gp + 100 gp per character level you have beyond 1st. If you do not
> have sufficient wealth to purchase this additional equipment, you feel
> a strong desire (but are not compelled) to sell existing items or
> steal from others to obtain it. **You are sickened** whenever you do not
> meet this requirement; **you are also sickened** for 24 hours after
> anything worth 25 gp × your character level or more is taken from you
> against your will.

while the [Plagued](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/Oracle/oracle-curses/#Plagued) curse states (emphasis mine)

> You take a –1 penalty on all saving throws against disease or
> infestation effects, but **you are immune to the sickened condition**.

If I'm not mistaken, then RAW that means you don't get any drawback from the [Covetous](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/Oracle/oracle-curses/#Covetous) curse, even when not wearing fancy clothing. But since the second curse isn't supposed to give you benefits only, that does seem kind of wrong.

Is there any official ruling on that? How would you handle that?

Right now, I would probably go with "*The character is immune to the sickened condition from all sources but the [Covetous](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/Oracle/oracle-curses/#Covetous) curse*" or have the player play up the mentioned desire they have (when not wearing fancy clothing) to sell or steal items to make roleplaying encounters more challenging in return.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. Thank you for pointing out the covetous curse. It's a good thing that the [noble's outfit](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipmenT/goods-and-services/containers-bags-boxes-more/#TOC-Outfit-Noble-s) allows paying any amount for jewelry; otherwise, encumbrance (not to mention comfort!) would be an issue with level 20 covetous oracles trying to wear 5 or more royal outfits! Anyway, thank you for a great first question and for your participation. Have fun!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### RAW this works

As you've noted, one makes you Sickened while the other makes you immune to Sickened. Per the rules on [Immunity](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Immunity_Ex_or_Su),

> [...] Immunities can also apply to afflictions, conditions, spells (based on school, level, or save type), and other effects. A creature that is immune does not suffer from these effects, or any secondary effects that are triggered due to an immune effect.

### However

The Oracle [Curse](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/Oracle/#Oracles_Curse_Ex) Feature provides that it is unnaturally resilient to tampering.

> The oracle’s curse cannot be removed or dispelled without the aid of a deity.

Because of this, and for balance reasons, I would absolutely rule as you state; the Oracle can be immune to Sickened *except* from their own second Curse.